# Subtract one absolute path from another in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, path

I have two paths in Node.js, e.g.:

```
var pathOne = '/var/www/example.com/scripts';
var pathTwo = '/var/www/example.com/scripts/foo/foo.js';
```

How do I subtract one path from another in order to obtain a relative path?

```
subtractPath(pathTwo, pathOne); // => 'foo/foo.js'
```

Is there a module that does this according to all necessary URL rules or do I better use some simple string manipulations?

Comment: use `substring` e.g : ```var sub = pathTwo.substring(pathOne.length, pathTwo.length);```

Comment: I think `pathTwo.repalce(pathOne,'')` enough

Comment: And what if one of paths is malformed? It will produce an incorrect result, e.g.: `'/var/www/example.com/scri'` will give us `pts/foo/foo.js` which can't be right.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "according to all necessary URL rules", but it seems you should be able to just use [`path.relative`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_relative_from_to);

```
> var pathOne = '/var/www/example.com/scripts';
> var pathTwo = '/var/www/example.com/scripts/foo/foo.js';

> path.relative(pathOne, pathTwo)
'foo/foo.js'

> path.relative(pathTwo, pathOne)
'../..'
```

Comment: Thanks Joachim! It was silly of me not to look into `path` API first. Looks like I shouldn't rely on Google too much = )

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily with a regex:

```
var pathOne = /^\/your\/path\//
var pathTwo = '/your/path/appendix'.replace(pathOne, '');
```

This way you can force it to be at the start of the second path (using `^`) and it won't be erased if it isn't an exact match.

Your example would be:

```
var pathOne = /^\/var\/www\/example.com\/scripts\//;
var pathTwo = '/var/www/example.com/scripts/foo/foo.js'.replace(pathOne, '');
```

It should return: `foo/foo.js`.

Comment: This isn't very useful. Presumably the path will be a variable input from somewhere, not a hard-coded string; in that case, how do you convert it to a regex? (It can be done, but there are edge cases to consider.)

Comment: Btw something like `new Regex('^'+p.replace('/','\/'))`. As long as it is read once and used multiple times, this solution is a valid one. Include a whole external library to replace a one line command is far from being a good idea, from my point of view.

Comment: More like `new RegExp('^' + p.replace(/([\[\]\(\)\{\}\.\\\/\?\*\+\|\^\$])/, '\\$1'))`. And that's assuming I haven't missed any out. Then you've also got to worry about cases like `/foo/bar` versus `/foo/baz`, and probably treat it differently depending on whether it has a trailing `/`. Also, `path` isn't an external library, it's part of nodejs.